# Bind user to virtual box os

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, user-accounts

I have Windows 7 Host and Windows XP guest in virtual box. Is it possible to somehow bind a particular user to that guest OS. I want to create some test environments for particular users. The idea is when that user logs in it automatically logs him in to the virtual XP environment and no other access to Windows 7 environment.